# FastAPI works in swagger but can't be called on React Native with Heroku as server

Tags: python, react-native, heroku, fastapi

I have a FASTAPI that accepts base64 string of image. In swagger, I have tried out the FASTAPI and it works without any problems. The request body is application/json. However, when I tried to call it in React Native app, it gives the following error. The header content-type is also application/json and the input of body that is accepted is str as per my FASTapi input but why did it use 'loc':[Array]. What makes it weird is that when I change the content-type of header to 'multiple/form-data', it will always run the except function. I have been stuck on this matter for some time. Any help will be highly appreciated.How could I solve this?
[image]

```
const getImg = async imageUrl => {
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const imageBlob = await response.blob();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      setImgUrl(base64data);
    };
  };
const chooseFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 3000,
      height: 4000,
      cropping: false,
    }).then(image => {
      getImg(image.path);
      hi();
    });
  };
const hi = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://receipt-ocr-heroku.herokuapp.com/receiptOcr',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          imagedata: imgUrl,
        }),
      },
    );
    console.log(response);
    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  };
```

FastAPI

```
import cv2
import base64
from processModule import *
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]

)


@app.post("/receiptOcr")
async def main(imagedata: str = Body(...)):
    try:
        # image = await file.read()
        # image = cv2.imread(image)
        img = base64.b64decode(imagedata)

        nparr = np.fromstring(img, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        # img = cv2.imread(img)
        resize_ratio = 500 / img.shape[0]
        # Duplicate Image
        original = img.copy()
        # Resize Image
        resizeImg = opencv_resize(img, resize_ratio)
        # Convert to grayscale for further processing
        grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(resizeImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Convert to Binary Image
        ret, binImg = cv2.threshold(
            grayImg, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        # Detect all contours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
            binImg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        image_with_contours = cv2.drawContours(
            img.copy(), contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # Get 10 largest contours
        largest_contours = sorted(
            contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]
        image_with_largest_contours = cv2.drawContours(
            img.copy(), largest_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
        # approximate the contour by a more primitive polygon shape

        receipt_contour = get_receipt_contour(largest_contours)

        image_with_receipt_contour = cv2.drawContours(
            img.copy(), [receipt_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        scanned = wrap_perspective(
            original.copy(), contour_to_rect(receipt_contour, resize_ratio))

        result = bw_scanner(scanned)

        ret, img = cv2.threshold(result, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        receiptResize = opencv_resize(img, 0.5)

        wordArr = wordDetectionAndExtraction(receiptResize)

        totalPrice = index_containing_substring(
            wordArr, 'total', 'sub')

        return {"totalPrice": totalPrice}

    except:
        response = '0'
        return {"totalPrice": response}
```

Comment: Since you haven't included what `imgUrl` is it's hard to say - maybe it's null, maybe it's an object, maybe it's an array - you would also be be better off by logging the actual body of the response, instead of the response itself (so that you get the actual content of the Array in the middle there) (you can retrieve the body with `await response.text()`). Don't catch all exceptions and do nothing (especially not when debugging) - it'll hide any good hints about the error that you're trying to debug. Since it works in swagger - how are you adding the base64 encoded data in swagger?

Comment: This is also the fourth question about the same-ish issue; it'd be far more helpful if you interacted with those questions where you've received both comments for more details and actual answers, instead of creating a new, almost identical question each time.